# zooming in and out using mouse scroll wheel

Tags: mouse, zooming

I searched desperately for a way to do that but in vain. so far it looks like the only way for zooming using mouse in android is clicking twice the left button and dragging up or down, which is very awkward and frustrating and out of common sense. I tried to find a key mapper on Googleplay but I found nothing which handles mouse buttons. I also looked for an image viewer with any options for mouse input, and nothing I found.

Comment: Do you mean something like clicking Ctrl and scrolling?

Comment: I mean zooming just through scrolling like image viewer in windows or like any 3d modelling program